# Доступ к API. PHP vs Python 3

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, json, api

Всем добра. Посоветуйте на чем лучше осуществлять доступ к API сайта. Есть несколько сайтов у всех у них есть API. На каком языке программирования лучше осуществлять доступ к API и последующую обработку ответа. Обработка результата будет осуществляться следующим образом, получение ответа от сайта(JSON), обработка результата и запись результата в базу. Есть начальные знания PHP и Python. На Python мной написан скрипт для обработки результатов, правда пока без записи в базу. Базу предполагаю использовать MySQL. Вот думаю переписать все на PHP или дописать на Python.